# PHP: catching a fatal error (call to member function on a non-object)

Tags: php, error-handling

Sometimes, my script cannot read output by a server and the following error occurs:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function somefun() on a non-object`

This is not something that can't be fixed on my end but this causes my script to crash. Is there a way I can create a function that gets run when this particular error occurs? I don't think it's practical to make a try-catch or similar because I would have to find every instance where a member function gets called and test whether the object exists or not (several thousand).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Comment: I don't see anything in the manual about this

Comment: You cannot catch a fatal error.

Comment: @octern yes, but I would have to do this check in thousands of locations. I want to know if there is a better method

Comment: There is an approved RFC to make this error catchable: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/catchable-call-to-member-of-non-object
It is not released yet, but will probably be in PHP next minor version.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### In PHP 7

Yes, catch an "Error" throwable, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Be26l

```
<?php

$x = "not an object";

try {
 $x->foo();
} catch (\Throwable $t) {
 echo "caught";
}
```

### In PHP 5

> Is there a way I can create a function that gets run when this particular error occurs?

Yes, you can use "[register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)" to get PHP to call a function just before it dies after encountering this error.

> PHP: catching a fatal error (call to member function on a non-object)

It is not possible to recover from this error, if that is what you mean by "catch", as PHP has defined "Call to a member function on a non-object" as a "fatal" error. See [PHP turn "Call to a member function on a non-object" into exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502559) for some discussion on why this might be.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php. You would have to write your own error handler and check the errorcode for whether you want to display the error or not.

Comment: What level error is the one I'm having? `E_ERROR`? If so, this wouldn't work

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. Is creating a dummy-function an option? Or is the function name created dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

try use [function_exists](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check that function is exist:

```
if (function_exists("somefun")) {
   ...
}
```

or use [method_exists](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to validate class method.

Comment: I am already aware of this solution but the problem is that this can happen anywhere in the code (maybe a 1000 different places), I don't want to duplicate this that many times

Comment: If you were able to catch the error, would you be able to respond to it in a generic way that's applicable in all 1000 places? Or would the possible error conditions all need to do something different in response anyway?

Comment: I would be able to respond appropriately